# Is it possible to change files with recordings (answers) in freePBX, Asterisk during talk?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

In IVR (freePBX) there are answers recorded that are played when someone is calling  , but is it possible to change those answers via REST API or switch recordings "on fly"?
I am looking for a way to synthesize answers during talk.

Comment: If this function is available, it will be documented. What has your research shown you?

Answer (score 0):

RestAPI module is commercial module from Sangoma.

However if you want just change messages, path to files  stored in db in **recordings** table.

So should be not a problem hire freelancer who did this single api call for you.

Please note, asterisk able play only very few formats, so you need convert it first.

If you need text-to-speech, that is slightly more complex staff if do via api, but there is availible module named **TTS**(free one), which can do text from db table.